# Add +1 to my json file each time the command executed (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I want to be able to add +1 each time the command executed on my bot, but with the code I have now it can only go to 2, I use fs const for do this

```
  invites:  1 ,  
};
invite.invites++ ;
  fs.writeFile("./invite.json", JSON.stringify(invite), err => {
    if (err) console.log("Error writing file:", err);
  });
```

This is the full command (if it usefull to help me)

```
if (!admins.includes(message.author.id)){ 
    if (message.channel == '911286117477802082'){
      if (message.author.bot) return;
      let unlimitedMessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle("Advertising Center")
     .setDescription(`<:purpleright:912726393375293441>・All invite for nitro server & account selling are **Not Allow** \n
     <:purpleright:912726393375293441>・All Nsfw server need to be post here <#911352615902781483> \n 
      <:purpleright:912726393375293441>・ If you quit all of your invite gonna be deleted 
     `)
     .setTimestamp()
     .setColor("#23ff00")
     .setFooter(`Bot created by: Kingツ#4489 `)
   message.channel.send({ embeds: [unlimitedMessage] })
    return };
    if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/'||'discordapp.com/invite/')){
    if (message.channel.parent == '927599828341510185'){
      if (message.author.bot) return;
    let user =  message.author;
  if (message.content.length < 30) {
    message.delete()
    // console.log(message)
     let addDescription = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle("Advertising Center")
     .setDescription(`You need to add one descripion of your server for post Advertising ${user}`)
     .setTimestamp()
     .setColor("#ff0000")
     .setFooter(`Bot created by: Kingツ#4489 `)
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [addDescription] })
    let inviteLogBad = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle("Invite Track")
     .setDescription(`Username: ${user}\n \n Channel: ${message.channel}\n \nInvite : ${message.content.includes('discord.gg/'||'discordapp.com/invite/' )} \n \n Description : ${message.content.length > 30} message content : ${message.content}`)
     .setTimestamp()
     .setColor("#ff0000")
       client.channels.cache.get(`927601147534000148`).send({ embeds: [inviteLogBad] })
     }else if
    (message.content.length > 30){
      if (message.author.bot) return;

    let serverMessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle("Advertising Center")
     .setDescription(`<:purpleright:912726393375293441>・All invite for nitro server & account selling are **Not Allow** \n
     <:purpleright:912726393375293441>・All Nsfw server need to be post here <#911352615902781483> \n 
     <:purpleright:912726393375293441>・your advertisement need to contains a description & unlimited invite link.\n
      <:purpleright:912726393375293441>・You can post every **2 hours**.\n
      <:purpleright:912726393375293441>・ If you quit all of your invite gonna be deleted 
     `)
     .setTimestamp()
     .setColor("#23ff00")
     .setFooter(`Bot created by: Kingツ#4489 `)
   message.channel.send({ embeds: [serverMessage] })
 
      const invite = {
  invites:  1 ,  
};
invite.invites++ ;
  fs.writeFile("./invite.json", JSON.stringify(invite), err => {
    if (err) console.log("Error writing file:", err);
  });
   let inviteLogGood = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle("Invite Track")
     .setDescription(`Username: ${user}\n \n Channel: ${message.channel}\n \nInvite : ${message.content} \n \n Message link: ${message.url} `)
     .setTimestamp()
     .setColor("#23ff00")
       client.channels.cache.get(`927601147534000148`).send({ embeds: [inviteLogGood] })
      }
     }else{
       let user =  message.author;
       if (message.author.bot) return;
       message.delete()
       message.channel.send(`You can't send invite link here ${user}, Please go on Advertising channel for do that`)   
}
}
    }
```

Comment: because you would need to read the file on the server to get the latest value. You create the object with one. `const invite = {
  invites:  1 ,  
};` <--- always going to be one.

Comment: Should also note, this is not going to scale well.

Comment: do you have another idea ? This is the first time I use Json file so idk what is the best for do what I need to do

Comment: You need to read the JSON file before you add one to it. No where do I see you reading the JSON value.